# Loop until all events are received in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that waits for four external events (I have no control on them. They are randomly received)

```
function Foo() {
    var this.data_1;
    var this.data_2;
    var this.data_3;
    var this.data_4;
}
Foo.prototype.getData = function(){

    deviceOne.on('data', (data) => {
         this.data_1 = data;
    });
    deviceTwo.on('data', (data) => {
         this.data_2 = data;
    });
    deviceThree.on('data', (data) => {
         this.data_3 = data;
    });
    deviceFour.on('data', (data) => {
         this.data_4 = data;
    });
    return {
        "data_from_device_1": this.data_1,
        "data_from_device_2": this.data_2,
        "data_from_device_3": this.data_3,
        "data_from_device_4": this.data_4
    }
};
var foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.getData()); // {'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined'}
```

As you can see, the function won't wait for them and it will return 4 undefined objects. I've been looking for a solution and it seems like using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) could help. It's just I didn't understand how to use it correctly in my case

Comment: Do you mind console log events separately when each is calledback? If so you can log inside each callback.

Comment: does each `device*` emit one and only one `data` event?

Comment: @JaromandaX - Good question. Even if they don't, the intent of the above *seems* to be to capture the next one, but it's a good question.

Comment: Side note: Your `var this.data_1;` and such in `Foo` are invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `async` (and it does help here), first you need to do a promise version of your `deviceXYZ.on`:

```
const waitForData = device => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    device.on('data', (data) => {
         resolve(data);
    });
    // ...presumably hook up some kind of error event and use `reject` here...
});
```

Then (I've converted to `class` syntax here since if you're using `async`, you can use the new, simpler notation):

```
class Foo {
    async getData() {
//  ^^^^^
        const data = await Promise.all([
        //           ^^^^^
            waitForData(deviceOne),
            waitForData(deviceTwo),
            waitForData(deviceThree),
            waitForData(deviceFour)
        ]);
        this.data_1 = data[0];
        this.data_2 = data[1];
        this.data_3 = data[2];
        this.data_4 = data[3];
        return {
            data_from_device_1: this.data_1,
            data_from_device_2: this.data_2,
            data_from_device_3: this.data_3,
            data_from_device_4: this.data_4
        };
    }
}
```

Then code using it also has to be in an `async` function:

```
(  async () => {
// ^^^^^
    try {
        const foo = new Foo();
        console.log(await foo.getData()); // {'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined', 'undefined'}
        // ---------^
    } catch (e) {
        // Handle/report error
    }
})();
```

...or it can use the promise directly in a non-`async` function:

```
const foo = new Foo();
foo.getData()
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // Handle/report error
    });
```

More:

- [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
- [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
- [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)
- [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class)
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

---

Side note: This is invalid syntax:

```
function Foo() {
    var this.data_1; // Error here
    var this.data_2;
    var this.data_3;
    var this.data_4;
}
```

At the moment, you don't declare properties in JavaScript. However, before too long (possibly ES2019, almost certainly ES2020) `class` syntax will be extended by the class fields proposal, currently at Stage 3 in the proposals process. When that happens, you can declare the "shape" of objects created by the `Foo` class (which can mean the objects go through fewer shape changes, which helps improve performance; it's also useful documentation for people reading the code). That would change `Foo` to look like this:

```
class Foo {
    data_1; // These are field (property) declarations
    data_2;
    data_3;
    data_4;

    async getData() {
        // ...
    }
}
```